# Beautifulsoup - how to get text from <span>'s

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a website. All is going fine, but I want to find the text between `<span>`. I can retrieve the 1st one, but I cant get to the next ones.
This is the html excerpt:

```
<ul class="product-small-specs" data-test="product-specs">
    <li>
    <span>Engels</span>
    </li>
    <li>
    <span>Hardcover</span>
    </li>
    <li>
    <span>9780141395838</span>
    </li>
    <li>
    <span>Druk: New ed</span>
    </li>
    <li>
    <span>oktober 2014</span>
    </li>
    <li>
    <span>352 pagina's</span>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

When I try this:

```
xxx.span.text
```

I get `'Engels'` (which is ok).

But how do I get the text between the next 'span's?

```
xxx.span.next_sibling
```

gives `'/n'`

Any help would be highly appreciated.

edit:
The url is [this](https://www.bol.com/nl/s/algemeen/zoekresultaten/Ntt/nietzsche%2Bbeyond%2Bgood%2Band%2Bevil/N/0/Nty/1/search/true/searchType/qck/suggestionType/search_history/originalSearchContext/media_all/originalSection/main/defaultSearchContext/media_all/sc/media_all/index.html)

```js
rec_all = soup.find_all("ul", class_="product-small-specs")
rec = soup.find("ul", class_="product-small-specs")

for iets in rec_all:
    for a in iets:
        print(a.span.text)
        print(a.span.next_sibling)
```

Comment: first show your code and url for this page. Maybe page uses JavaScript to add items and BS can't run JavaScript.

Comment: maybe you should use `find_all('span')` to get list with all `span` and then use `for`-loop to get text from every element on list.

Comment: rec_all = soup.find_all("ul", class_="product-small-specs")
rec = soup.find("ul", class_="product-small-specs")

for iets in rec_all:
    for a in iets:
        print(a.span.text)
        print(a.span.next_sibling)

Comment: url is [link](https://www.bol.com/nl/s/algemeen/zoekresultaten/Ntt/nietzsche%2Bbeyond%2Bgood%2Band%2Bevil/N/0/Nty/1/search/true/searchType/qck/suggestionType/search_history/originalSearchContext/media_all/originalSection/main/defaultSearchContext/media_all/sc/media_all/index.html)

Comment: always put code, data and error messages in question - it will be more readable and more people will see it.

Comment: xxx means you are in li tag ,  it has just one span with no sibling spans

Comment: what you want is xxx.parent.li.nextsibling.span.text

Comment: or say xxx.nextsibling.span.text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find_all("span")` to get list with all `<span>` and then you can use `for`-loop to get text from every item on list

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

text = '''<ul class="product-small-specs" data-test="product-specs">
    <li>
    <span>Engels</span>
    </li>
    <li>
    <span>Hardcover</span>
    </li>
    <li>
    <span>9780141395838</span>
    </li>
    <li>
    <span>Druk: New ed</span>
    </li>
    <li>
    <span>oktober 2014</span>
    </li>
    <li>
    <span>352 pagina's</span>
    </li>
</ul>'''


soup = BS(text, 'html.parser')

all_items = soup.find_all('span')

for item in all_items:
    print(item.text)
```

Result:

```
Engels
Hardcover
9780141395838
Druk: New ed
oktober 2014
352 pagina's
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you need all `<span>` in selected `<ul>` then you can use

```
ul = soup.find('ul', class_="product-small-specs")

all_items = ul.find_all('span') # search only inside `ul`

for item in all_items:
    print(item.text)
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you have more `ul` and more `span` in `li` then you can use nested `for`-loops

```
soup = BS(text, 'html.parser')

for ul in soup.find_all("ul", class_="product-small-specs"):
    print('--- ul ---')
    for li in ul.find_all('li'):
        print('  --- li ---')
        for span in li.find_all('span'):
            print('    span:', span.text)
```

Result:

```
--- ul ---
  --- li ---
    span: Engels
  --- li ---
    span: Hardcover
  --- li ---
    span: 9780141395838
  --- li ---
    span: Druk: New ed
  --- li ---
    span: oktober 2014
  --- li ---
    span: 352 pagina's
```

Comment: the problem is that there are hundreds of span's on the page. I would like to get the text from the span only in this part (ul class = ...)

Comment: then uses `find` or `find_all` to get `<ul>` and then you can search inside this item usinig `ul` instead of `soup` - see added code.

Comment: thanks a lot! This is what I was looking for. Breaking my head for hours on this! THX!